# Audience poll "Guess a number"

Tags: web-apps, survey

For a presentation, I want the audience to guess a number (E.g. "What is the smallest prime number greater than 1000?"). It should be accessible through their phones. Since I want to make a game out of it, I need to be able to identify the first one who got the right answer. I am looking for one of the following two realizations:

- Something similar to "Mentimeter's" open-ended questions. In this case, everyone in the audience submits as many guesses as they want, and the submissions are displayed for everyone to see, in real time, with the *nicknames* visible. I would then spot the first correct submission, and be able to identify the 'winner' by his/her nickname.
- Alternatively, they could enter their guesses, but I provide the poll with the correct answer, and the website automatically identifies the winner once the correct answer has been entered, and stops the polling.

Important features would be:

- Nickname are visible for every answer (e.g. I can 'switch off' anonymity)
- every user can post multiple answers (they can guess till someone gets it right)
- everyone can access the poll with his/her phone.
- it's free.

I have looked at several options, but I couldn't find any platform offering the non-anonymity I need. I would appreciate any suggestions!